# How to get workflow task list by ItemId with relatedItems?

Tags: task-list

How can i get task list with itemId programatically? Task list has a column named ReletadeItems, but this is formatted string,json.

I have ListItemId(ID) value, I want to get task list by this ListItemId with Caml query.

I can get all task list items and with foreach loop, parse reletadItems, then get ItemId. But I think this is not the apropriate way. I want to write caml query and getItems with caml query. How can i do that?

Forexample; this is reletadeItems value:

```
[{"ItemId":116,"WebId":"431c9bc1-67c6-4b49-9907-12f3bfbe5652","ListId":"349b2097-97ed-4d4f-976f-78700b2e2899"}]
```

I want to get task list items with ItemId..

Answer (score -1):

For those who are trying the same using CSOM.

Step 1: First query the list in which the workflow is running with Item ID - 2

Step 2: Read the Field name which is created with your workflow name. 'VetriWorkFlow' is the workflow name and field name.

```
(FieldUrlValue)mlstItems[0].FieldValues["VetriWorkFlow"];
```

Step 3: In this field you will be able to see an instance id. Capture the same and pass it to 'WF4InstanceId' column in Workflow Tasks list.

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='WF4InstanceId' /><Value Type='Text'>#instanceID</Value></Eq></Where>
```

Result: You will get the list of tasks that are created for the list item 2.